# how to quickly create large dxf from geometrical shapes

Tags: python, cad, dxf

I have a 2D pattern consisting of ~10 million circles, stored in the form of a list

`[[x, y, radius], [x, y, radius], ...]`

I want to turn it into a DXF (a common CAD file format). I tried [dxfwrite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dxfwrite/) and [ezdxf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ezdxf/) and they both work but very slowly. (If I extrapolate from smaller tests, dxfwrite would take ~12 hours and ezdxf ~4 hours.)

Is there any way to do this substantially faster?

(The list is in Python to start with, but I don't mind exporting to a text file and then using a different program.)

Comment: If I understand your problem, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7bgeVwj7Dk) could help.

Comment: At a glance, the [DXF file format](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acadr14/dxf/ascii_dxf_file_format_al_u05_b.htm) appears simple enough to not need a functional library. Depending on the format of your original list, possibly all you need is adding the header and per-object information with a plain text editor capable of search-and-replace.

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: If you create a .dxf file containing 10 million entities, it will crash pretty much any CAD software that tries to open it.  Maybe re-think this as a raster image display instead of vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just circles you can use the simple DXF R12 format with just an ENTITIES section:

```
  0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
CIRCLE
  8
0
 10
{x-coord}
 20
{y-coord}
 40
{radius}
  0
ENDSEC
  0
EOF
```

The following Python script creates a DXF file with 10.000.000 circles in less than a minute on a CAD workstation. AutoCAD needs less than 3 minutes to open it, but AutoCAD is not responsive anymore.

```
from random import random

MAX_X_COORD = 1000.0
MAX_Y_COORD = 1000.0
MAX_R = 1.0
CIRCLE_COUNT = 10000000

def dxf_circle(x, y, r):
    return "0\nCIRCLE\n8\n0\n10\n{x:.3f}\n20\n{y:.3f}\n40\n{r:.2f}\n".format(x=x, y=y, r=r)

with open("circles.dxf", 'wt') as f:
    f.write("0\nSECTION\n2\nENTITIES\n")
    for i in range(CIRCLE_COUNT):
        f.write(dxf_circle(MAX_X_COORD*random(), MAX_Y_COORD*random(), MAX_R*random()))
    f.write("0\nENDSEC\n0\nEOF\n")
```

Comment: This is helpful.  To do other shapes, I found the DXF specification https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf to be useful, especially Chapter 9 which describes the file format itself.